# Why does import package.module.function fail in python?

Tags: python

I've tried googling (to little avail) to more clearly understand what different meaning period . has during an import statement, vs. once a module has already been imported.

For example, these all work:

```
import numpy
X = numpy.random.standard_normal
```

---

```
from numpy.random import standard_normal
```

---

```
import numpy.random
```

but this doesn't work:

```
import numpy.random.standard_normal
```

I'm a bit confused as to why this is. Why is there a difference in what the period . does when accessing a module before vs. after an import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `standard_normal` is a method

```
<built-in method standard_normal of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x0000029D722FBD40>
```

whenever you do `from numpy.random import standard_normal` you are importing the method

and i don't think you can do this `import numpy.random.standard_normal` cause `standard_normal` again is a method, this would be possible if `standard_normal` would be some module.

Take a look at this, you when I typed `dir(standard_normal)` I get the output of those things which are `attributes` and when I typed `standard_normal` it says `<built-in method standard_normal of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x000002509D504740>` cause it simply says it is a method

[image: sample]

Now when I did this `import numpy.random.standard_normal` , you are expecting to import the method right? But what it really does is trying to import a module, Well... there is no such thing as `standard_normal` module or `standard_normal.py` file.

Take a look at this again. I imported the `random` module and I used the `.` operator to access the `standard_normal function`. You can see the sense of it right. Cause on the `random.py` module it has there a `standard_normal` function or method.

[image: sampe]

Sorry I had to use the CMD.

Comment: I observed that, but I was curious if there's some underlying issue as to why the import X.Y statement only works for modules, rather than functions.

Comment: @user49404 why do you think it's an issue? It's how the language works... You `import` **modules**. If you just want to have the name of a specific function from another module you can do `from module import function`

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's not an issue, I was just curious why the language was designed that way.

Comment: @user49404 , why may I ask are there other programming languages that you have experienced that applies on what you these concept like `import random.random.standard_normal` actually imports the `standard_normal` function. Cause I think that's not how it works with python.

Comment: @IceBear I don't have any other languages in mind, I understand this is just how python works, I was just sort of curious if there was some underlying design concern as to why they chose to do things this way.

Comment: @user49404 seems logic and consistent... Pretty straightforward also `import (the module) module` and `from (the module) module import (the function) function` (parenthesis added to illustrate how to read the actual code). Anyway this kind of questions can't be answered here... We are just experienced users, it is a question for the designers of the language